# Label only features that intersect a specific line

Tags: qgis, labeling, style

hello I have two lines layers in QGIS `line1` and `line2` with field `my_field`(line1) and `label`(line2).

I have a global project variable `label_filter=one`

[image: global]

now I want to create a base label rule,first I want to filter line1 with project variable `label_filter`  using something like this `my_field like label_filter` to show only that labels and after this filter to create addition rule to show only the labels from line2 where have intersect with line1.

i try this but without success :

```
 geomintersects("line1",'my_field') and dbquery('line1','my_field','my_field like  @label_filter ')
```

first image :

[image: image1]

that I want :

[image: image 2]